# Validate a form before running calculations

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, input

I'm working on a short project where two numbers are submitted. One must be at least 100, a second cannot exceed 100. Three calculations are run, then printed back.

I've tried various methods, but I can't get the javascript to stop the functions in invalid numbers are submitted. The form will return 0's, but that's the best I've found so far.

What I'm trying to do:

1. Enter number
2. Validate numbers -If invalid, stop now, print error    -If valid, continue
3. Continue calculations
4. Print results

Codepen: http://codepen.io/uggh/pen/bpvmdz

```
function checkNumbers() {
  if (isNaN(sqft.value) == true) {
    returnError.innerHTML = "Please insert number A";
  } else if (isNaN(desired.value) == true) {
    returnError.innerHTML = "Please insert number B";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call your `Calculate` function from the `checkNumbers` function

```
function checkNumbers() {
  if (isNaN(sqft.value) == true) {
    returnError.innerHTML = "Please insert number A";
  } else if (isNaN(desired.value) == true) {
    returnError.innerHTML = "Please insert number B";
  }


 else{
    return calculate();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to have `checkNumbers` return something that could then be checked in an `if` statement to decide whether or not to continue processing.  Your current code calls `calculate` regardless of what happens inside of `checkNumbers`.

Also, your test for checking your number fields is wrong: if one isn't a valid number, its `value` is an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

you can change your **onclick** to look like this:

```
if(checkNumbers()){calculate();compare();food();}
```

and make your function **checkNumbers()** return true if everything is good and false if there's an error.